# MVVMLight does not add ViewLocator and ViewModel to my WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Ok, after adding MVVMLight to my WPF application, no viewlocator or viewmodel was added to the project. I added it through nuget.
I also tried MVVMLightLibs but the same results.
Any help on using MVVMLight in WPF applications, esp. with the initial installation.
I even downgraded the MVVMLight version but to no avail.
I followed this tutorial [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-mvvm-light-with-wpf/). Shot of the vs editor showing the project is also
 [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlTsx.png)

I am using .NET Core (v3.1).

Comment: What type of WPF app project are you creating? .NET Framework, .NET Core, or .NET 5?

Comment: I don't think adding mvvmlightlibs has the effect claimed in that article. It would be unusual for a nuget package to add a folder and weird to add source code.  Personally, i wouldn't use viewmodellocator anyhow. For net 5 i copied in source code of the package for the parts i wanted to a class library. Iirc there was an incompatibility somewhere in the package.  That was as a while ago and i've not checked to see whether laurent updated the nuget packages since.

Comment: @TamBui a .NET Core (v3.1) application

Comment: @Andy I see. I guess I will have to do it manually then. Thanks guys